# Python - Problem coding random number guessing game using while loop

Tags: python, random, while-loop, numbers

first time poster.  I'm having a problem getting my random number guessing game in Python to work properly.  I've purposely set the number to not be random (it's 50) for testing purposes.  If I guess a number under 50, it will tell me that the number is higher;  I can then guess higher than 50 and it will tell me lower.

For some reason though, if I guess above 50 and then try to guess under 50, the program stops.

Can someone point me in the right direction please? Here is my code:

```
from random import randint
randomNum = 50 #randint(0,100)
print("Let's play a guessing game.  I'm thinking of a number between 0-100. Take a guess 
what it is") 
num = int(input()) 
if(num == randomNum):
    print("Wow, what fantastic luck!  You're right!")
while (randomNum > num):
    print('Its higher than that. Guess again!')
    num = int(input())
    while (num == randomNum):
        print("You got it!")
        break

while (randomNum < num):
    print('Its lower than that! Guess again!')
    num = int(input())
    while (num == randomNum):
        print("You got it!")
        break
```

Comment: The two loops are supposed to run in sequence, but probably you need one loop to determine and inform you if it is high or low on each input?

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue, when you guess first, you enter your first while loop

```
while (randomNum > num):
    print('Its higher than that. Guess again!')
    num = int(input())
    while (num == randomNum):
        print("You got it!")
        break
```

then you guess again with that second input, but if your number isnt higher than 50, then that while loop is over, and the program ends, wrapping th whole thing in a while loop and putting your input at the top like this:

```
num ='anything thats not an int'
while (num != randomnum):
    num = int(input())
    
    if randomNum > num:
        print('Its higher than that. Guess again!')

    elif randomNum < num:
        print('Its lower than that! Guess again!')
print('you guessed the number!')
```

the last print statement is outside the loop cause the loop will only break once num = randomnum